# Proof in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

*Let X, Y be sets of propositions in the propositional logic. Prove that $X \cup Y$ is satisfiable iff for every finite subset $W$ of $X$ it holds that $W \cup Y$ is satisfiable.*

This seems really obvious and I don't see what can be said in the proof, other than "there is an assignment such that $X \cup Y$ holds, and since W ⊆ X, W∪Y ⊆ X∪Y, therefore X∪Y ⊨ W∪Y, so W ∪ Y is satisfiable for all W ⊆ X."

Is this really it, or is there more to say?

Comment: Oh, just remembered I have to do the other direction too

Comment: You only proved one way (the easy way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the argument of the compactness theorem.

If $X \cup Y$ is inconsistent, then a contradiction can be deduced using only a finite number of propositions from $X$ (as an argument can only have a finite number of lines). Hence for some finite subset $W$ of $X$, $W \cup Y$ is inconsistent.

Since consistency is equivalent to satisfiablity (by the Soundness and Completeness Theorem), taking the contrapositive of the above should give you the other direction.